# Objective-C How can I upload a file to FTP server? (Simple)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, apache, ftp

My project I am currently working on will allow users to upload files to an apache FTP server and then a link will be generated for them to view the file.

Does anyone have code that works for them that they could share? Thanks

Comment: Solved now! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look to apple project SimpleFTPSample

you can find a complete project with code ...

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html